# sed why POSIX blacket expression needs to be in another blacket?

Tags: regex, sed, posix

### Qustion

What is the reason that POSIX expression such as [:space:] needs to be in another [ ] ?

```
$ echo "a b c" | sed 's/[:space:]*/_/g'
_ _b_ _

$ echo "a b c" | sed 's/[[:space:]]*/_/g'
_a_b_c_

$ echo "a b c" | sed 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/_/g'
a_b_c
```

---

### Update

[Regular Expressions/POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions)

> **Character classes**
>   The POSIX standard defines some classes or categories of characters as shown below. These classes are ***used within brackets***.

I had not understood what the character classes was but assumed it was a special character matching any white spaces, hence believed 's/[:space:]/_g/' would match space in-between "a b", however I suppose '[:space:]' itself would not match any character (please correct if this is still wrong).

I suppose [:space:] is like '\t\n\r\f\v' but by itself has no function. With blacket '[[:space:]]', it then has the function same as '[\t\n\r\f\v]'.

Comment: inside single `[]` the `:space:` is equivalent to `[:aceps]`.. also, what if you need to other characters? for ex: `echo 'a b c?d' | sed 's/[[:space:]?]/_/g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the terminology:

A **bracket expression** is a set of characters enclosed in `[` and `]` and can be used as such in a regexp. That set of characters can be represented by any combination of any of the following (and an optional initial `^` negation character):

1. A **character list**, e.g. `abcd...z`, or
2. A **character range**, e.g. `a-z`, or
3. A **character class**, e.g. `[:lower:]`

So `[:space:]` is a character class (representing all white space chars) and that can be used within a bracket expression `[...]` in a regexp just like if you specifically listed all white space chars within the bracket expression `[...]`. So this:

```
[:space:]
```

is just a character class, while this:

```
[[:space:]]
```

is a bracket expression which includes all white space chars and this:

```
[[:space:][:lower:]_#;A-D]
```

is a bracket expression which includes tall white space chars plus all lower case letters plus the chars _, #, and ; plus the letters in the range A through D (whatever those chars are in your locale).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood that I did not understand the basics of regex, and asked a wrong question.